# How is an IBOutlet UIViewController constructed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm extending Apple's template for [lazy table image loading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html). I would like the following code to run when RootViewController is constructed.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterForeground:)
name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification
object: nil];
```

The problem is I don't how how RootViewController is constructed. I tried the following two methods, but they were never executed. I put `NSLog` in those methods and they were never printed out.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
- (id)init
```

I opened MainWindow.xib and noticed that it loads RootViewController as an IBOutlet in the `UIApplicationDelegate`. Now, RootViewController is a subclass of `UIViewController`. So the question boils down to "how is an IBOutlet UIViewController constructed?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can executed the code you need to execute in the awakeFromNib method, this is called by the decoder once the outlet is created.

Comment: Can you explain why `-(id)init`, as defined in NSObject, did not execute? RootViewController -> UITableViewController -> UIViewController -> NSResponder -> NSObject.

Comment: A NIB file stores serialized objects. When you load the nib file, they get de-serialized, not created, so init methods aren't called.

Comment: thats why you have awakeFromnib, so you don't have to bother =)

Comment: I have no idea how to add `awakeFromNib` to my `UIViewController`. I imported `NSNibLoading.h` because that's where it's defined. And I appened `NSNibAwaking` to the protocol list.  Both lines I added said so and so was not defined. According to the docs `awakeFromNib` comes from the `AppKit.framework`. I couldn't even locate that framework in the list of existing frameworks. I'm totally lost.

Comment: awakeFromNib is added on to NSObject, all you have to do is add the method `-(void)awakeFromNib` to your RootViewController and it will be called.

Comment: @Scott Rice : dang, it's as simple as that! What didn't they just say that in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSNibAwaking_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)? I'm asking so I don't run into related issues in the future.

Comment: Its in the docs, but in a really bad place. Technically it is added on as a category of NSObject, so it is listed in a different file. One of the few times where I feel the Apple Documentation is lacking.

Comment: @JoJo: Description of the various ["Entry and Exit Points"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH5-SW6) for objects can be found in the Cocoa Fundamentals guide, for future reference.